# botocore.errorfactory.AuthorizationErrorException

Tags: python

I am getting error like this:

> botocore.errorfactory.AuthorizationErrorException: An error occurred
>   (AuthorizationError) when calling the Subscribe operation: User:
>   arn:aws:iam::904851140766:user/xxxxx is not authorized to perform:
>   SNS:Subscribe on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:141796722983

When using the following code:

```
def subscribe_numbers_to_topic(self, data):
    #print data
    nums = data.get('numbers')
    result = {}
    topic_arn = data.get('topic_arn')

def req(number):
    r = self.sns.subscribe( TopicArn=topic_arn, Protocol='sms', Endpoint=number )
```

Comment: share your code, where you are facing problem ?

Comment: def subscribe_numbers_to_topic(self, data):
  #print data
  nums = data.get('numbers')
  result = {}
  topic_arn = data.get('topic_arn')
  def req(number):
   r = self.sns.subscribe(
    TopicArn=topic_arn,
    Protocol='sms',
    Endpoint=number
   )

Comment: even got permissions from iam still getting that error.